Connection times out or is redirected to seperate virtual server on Nginx
I run a few deployments on Nginx, today, exclusively while connected to a VPN and browsing on any chromium based browser, the connection will time out (if the subdomain is the only one available to nginx) or be redirected to a seperate subdomain and error out due to the certificate being incorrect.
I have truly no idea why this set of circumstances happens.
The site is static, and built automatically with Jekyll on each git push.
I've disabled my firewall, removed QUIC from nginx conf and disabled it in chromium.
I've also manually tested with CURL. The time-outs continue while SSHd into the server, but curling it from my host machine with the VPN enabled works just fine, and browsing from firefox also works fine.
server {
        http2 on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        root /home/me/blog/_site;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri/ =404;
                rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                error_page 404 = /404.html;
        }

        location ~ \.html$ {
                internal;
        }

        location /rss.xml {
                return 301 https://example.com/feed.xml;
        }

        location /buttons/blogbutton.gif {
                return 301 https://example.com/assets/buttons/blogbutton.gif;
        }

        location /blogbutton.gif {
                return 301 https://example.com/assets/buttons/blogbutton.gif;
        }

        location /callback {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4832;
                proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Early-Data $ssl_early_data;
        }

        location /auth {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4832;
                proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Early-Data $ssl_early_data;
        }

        location /config.yml {
                try_files $uri /admin/config.yml =404;
        }
}

